# Residue Theory Question

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble calculating the following integral and would greatly appreciate any help.

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(1+\beta{cos\theta})^2}dx $, where $-1<\beta<1$.

What I have tried:

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$. Then $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$ and $cos(\theta)=1/2(z+\frac{1}{z})$. This gives: 
$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(1+\beta{cos\theta})^2}=1/i\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z(1+\frac{\beta}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z}))^2}$.

It gets a bit messy when I calculate this all out, and I am confused on how to proceed from there. Any help would be great!

Comment: Other than the fact that you have $d \theta$ and $dx$ in the integral, you have the right idea.